# Safari issue with writing-mode CSS property

Tags: css, safari

I have an issue with using the writing-mode CSS property on some button elements.
On Chrome it works fine, it looks like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```css
button {
height: auto;
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
padding: 12px 8px;
z-index: 50;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
rotate: 180deg;
}
```

On Safari the buttons look like this:

[image]

I had a look in Safari dev tools, in the Styles tab the writing-mode: vertical-lr is applied but if I look in Computed tab the writing-mode: horizontal-tb appears.
Did anyone had this issue before? Thank you

I tried setting different values for writing-mode in Safari but none of it applies.

Comment: Code as text please, not screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to fix the buttons, was to stop using:
`writing-mode: vertical-lr; rotate: 180deg;` 
and use this instead:
`transform: rotate(-90deg); transform-origin: bottom right;`

No issues on safari after this

Answer (score 1):

Japanese user forum suggested using something other than a button to be the button. I decided to do that:

[writing-mode: vertical-lr; がbuttonタグにだけ効かない。。](https://teratail.com/questions/frvtbi60o04vj2)